# Why is this query showing error ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected?

Tags: oracle, subquery, oracle-apex, oracle12c

I have a sql query, which on execution throws error as :

```
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
```

Below is the SQL :

```
SELECT A.Agent_key, Sum(Total_Orders) 

FROM

(SELECT A.Agent_key, Sum(Total_Orders)

     RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Sum(Total_Orders) ASC) AS Rank

     FROM Fact_Order F, Dim_Time T

     WHERE F.Time_Id = T.Time_Id AND T.Quarter= '1' AND

     TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY') = T.Year

     GROUP BY A.Agent_key

)

WHERE Rank < = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

- You are missing one comma after `Sum(Total_Orders)`
- You are also missing an alias for subquery (You are using `A.Agent_key` in outer select clause then `A` must be an alias of the subquery)
- `group by` clause in the outer query is missing. (You are using aggregation so `GROUP BY` is needed)
- alias for `sum(total_agents)` as you are referring to in the outer query

It should be

```
SELECT A.Agent_key, Sum(Total_Orders) 
FROM
(SELECT A.Agent_key, Sum(Total_Orders) as total_orders,
        RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Sum(Total_Orders) ASC) AS Rnk
   FROM Fact_Order F, Dim_Time T
  WHERE F.Time_Id = T.Time_Id
    AND T.Quarter= '1' 
    AND TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY') = T.Year
 GROUP BY A.Agent_key ) A
WHERE Rnk < = 1
GROUP BY A.Agent_key;
```